# SQL Msg 7399 and Msg 7303

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible that the main problem is not in SQL or in my PC but in Main Server that I am using?

- I tried Giving permission to Temp Folder.
- I tried Logging on an account or as local system in MSSQLSERVER.
- I tried changing AllowInProcess,DynamicParameters,AdHoc Distributed Queries, Show advance option.
- I tried different codes or ways to figure out.

But all of these fail.

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any information about the error. Msg
>   7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Cannot initialize the data source
>   object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server
>   "(null)".

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to a `NULL` linked server? What is the SQL you're running to get that error?

Comment: All codes i researched are the same as i am using right now. I also use linked server like "sp_addlinkedserver" but still, nothing happens.

Comment: All your tsql statements will be executed on the machine where your database instance is running. You mention "my PC" and "main server" which implies that there are at least 2 different machines involved. If your code is trying to access a file (or other resource) on your PC, this is not likely to ever work. Move your file (resource) to a location on the "main server" that your dba has established for this purpose. It can be a network share but the service account of your instance must have access to it.